# Как устранить странную зависимость количества отображаемых в RecyclerView элементов от параметра "максимальное количество строк" в соседнем TextView?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, textview, android-scrollview

Имеется фрагмент (его шаблон и классы лежат [здесь](https://gist.github.com/btow/4f5579e82dd36f199b37fb3f3f500515)) с корневым элементом ScrollView, который после создания выглядит так:

[image: Скриншот фрагмента сразу после его открытия]

Здесь красной рамкой обозначен TextView, у которого изначально устанавливается максимальное количество отображаемых строк равное трём. А красным кружком обозначена кнопка открытия списка характеристик (features), который реализован в виде RecyclerView. После её нажатия фрагмент выглядит так:

[image: Скриншот фрагмента после нажатия стрелки разворачивания свойств]

Здесь обозначенный красной рамкой RecyclerView показывает только 3 своих строки (при этом каждый элемент RecyclerView состоит из 2-х строк), а красным кружком - стрелка полного разворачивания описания. Поэтому для просмотра всех элементов списка характеристик (features) пользователю приходиться скролить именно этот участок экрана, что очень неудобно:

[image: Скриншот фрагмента при скроллинге RecyclerView]

После нажатия стрелки "Развернуть описание" (событие обрабатывается в строках 218-233 файла [FullGoodFragment.java](https://gist.github.com/btow/4f5579e82dd36f199b37fb3f3f500515#file-module_00_lib-src-main-java-com-example-module_00_lib-ui-fragment-cardview-fullgoodfragment-java-L218)) фрагмент выглядит так:

[image: Скриншот фрагмента после разворачивания описания]

Здесь красной рамкой отмечен TextView с изменённым слушателем нажатия "стрелки вниз" количеством строк в нём, а жёлтой - RecyclerView, в котором почему-то тоже изменилось количество отображаемых строк (было 3, а стало 5).

Вопрос: как отвязать отображение RecyclerView от настроек TextView?

Comment: покажите разметку. И опишите как должен список фич работать - таки скролиться как сейчас или нет. Если нет - то почему бы весь контент не сделать через Recycler? Надеюсь вы не обернули Recycler этот в ScrollView. Если да - то это плохая идея. Работать не будет. Откажитесь от вложенных скроллящихся контейнеров.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, разметка лежит [здесь] (https://gist.github.com/btow/4f5579e82dd36f199b37fb3f3f500515#file-module_00_lib-src-main-res-layout-module_00_fragment_full_good-xml).

Корневой элемент фрагмента именно ScrollView. :(

Если я для выделенного на скриншотах TextView устанавливаю maxLines = 4 (и, соответственно, меняю OnClickListener() под 4 строки), то всё работает как надо (см. жёлтую рамку на 4-м скриншоте) - фичи разворачиваются сразу полностью и не требуют скроллинга.

Comment: Это случайность. Выкрутить на максимум размер шрифта на девайса и всё поломается. Оставьте только что то одно. Ресайклер или скроллВью. Оба не надо. Это можно, но не без хаков, ломающий много всего

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а чем адекватно можно заменить RecyclerView или ScrollView, так, чтобы, соответственно, замена корректно работала со ScrollView или RecyclerView. 

Кстати, при изменении размера шрифта в настройках экрана приложение почему-то падает.

Comment: Можно заменить и тем и другим. ScrollView будет проще в реализации, но тормозить может при большом объеме вложенных элементов. RecyclerView лучше будет - просто разные ячейки там отображать и всё. Но это сложнее в реализации и организации структуры данных.

Comment: А у каждой ошибки есть имя и логи. По ним можно точно узнать что произошло

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, предыдущий комментарий про то, чем заменить до моего мозга не дошёл. Можно уточнить? Если оставлять ScrollView в качестве корневого элемента фрагмента, то чем заменить вложенные в него RecyclerView так, чтобы сохранялась возможность загружать в них данные из списка (или БД)? Или если оставлять вложенные RecyclreView, то чем заменить корневой ScrollView так, чтобы оставалась возможность скролить фрагмент?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66819/discussion-between-noname-noferstname-and-).

Comment: В чаты я не хожу. Если убрать Recycler, то его заменять программным добавлением вьюшек в ScrollView. Если убрать ScrollView, то весь его контент отображать в отдном RecyclerView. При раскрытии надо добавлять данные в список отображаения и заставлять Recycler перерисоваться. Это сложно, но это правильный путь.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, теперь понятнее. Спасибо! Буду пробовать.